# What size for Virtual Memory

Tags: virtual-memory

I am a total novice when it comes to hardware settings.

I am using Windows Server 2012 64 Bit.

It has 12GB RAM. I have a C and virtual D drive.

The build is i5-2400 3.10 GHz.

There is no current settiugs for virtual memory.

What is the rule of thumb please?

Comment: I'm assuming by "virtual memory" size that you're referring to the page file.  If you have no idea what it should be, then just set it to let Windows decide for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. Yes, I am looking at the Virtual Memory in the Performance Options in the properties of my computer.  It is currently set to default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't having problems, and don't have a specific reason otherwise, then just let Windows automatically set it for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you again for your time.  There is a check-box option to 'Automatically manage paging file size for all drives'. Is this what you meant? Thanks

Comment: Yup. If you need to keep the page file(s) off certain drives then uncheck that, and set each drive individually to either "System Managed Size" or "None" depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

By default, client version of Windows will allocate 1.5x the size of your physical memory in pagefile. That would be 18GB in your case. If you have two drives, I would recommend keeping the page file on the fastest of the two.

On a server, I would consider adding more memory instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.  I don't actually have any memory problem at the moment. I just purchased the server from FastHosts. I was just making sure everything is configured as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you're page swapping on a server (using virtual memory) I would suggest buying more memory. Your performance will suffer massively if page swapping is occurring. My rule of thumb is 0MB.

Comment: Disabling your page file is a bad idea in 99% of the cases, and it doesn't' work the way you seem to think it does. See: [Windows Swap (Page File): Enable or Disable?](http://superuser.com/questions/14795/windows-swap-page-file-enable-or-disable?lq=1), [Any reason not to disable the Windows pagefile given enough physical RAM?](http://superuser.com/questions/30345/any-reason-not-to-disable-the-windows-pagefile-given-enough-physical-ram), etc.

Comment: Both of those links seem to indicate that it either a) doesn't matter or b) may actually be better disabled. The more RAM option is definitely good advice in a situation where a page file MAY be used since it's significantly cheaper to upgrade than to deal with performance issues.