# Windows showing about 24.5GB used in drive but copying it shows a whole other story

Tags: windows-10

You can see in the screenshot that Drive F is showing 38GB free meaning 24.4GB is free but I wanted to transfer all the files from F to I so I did that but only 600MB transferred and looking at it closer, all the files in the drive F should be around 600MB so what is it that's taking up the space. I'm using Windows 10 Pro Version 2004.

Drive F shows 38GB free out of 63.2GB, Drive I shows 57.7 free out of 58.8GB:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I see no screenshot.  Try something like Disk Scanner, Windirstat, or something similar (there are many) ***RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR***.

Comment: Yeah I used that and I found out why it was showing incorrect data. I had a pagefile.sys that was about 6GB and Recycle Bin that is 16GB. Can I delete the pagefile?

Comment: [Any reason not to disable the Windows pagefile given enough physical RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/30345/any-reason-not-to-disable-the-windows-pagefile-given-enough-physical-ram/)

Comment: Technically, yes, but no, I wouldn't.  Keep SOME type of pagefile.  Either move it to another drive/partition or reduce it's size.  The size of the pagefile is dependent on how much ram you have.. it's complicated though.  With less than 6GB (a guessed number) , I would have about twice my ram size for pagefile.  As your ram goes up from there, you can start reducing your pagefile size.  It's more of a black art than a science as your ram gets bigger and bigger

Comment: So I have 4GB RAM on this system. So I should maintain at least 8GB? Also is the moving of pagefiles done in the advanced system properties in control panel

Comment: Also what about Recycle Bin. What do i do with that

Comment: @AadiSahni - Configure it to your personal preference.